# Is it safe to use one .so file to link but set another library with the same API in LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries, elf

In my case I have three libraries:

```
libOpenGlRenderer.so
libVulkanRenderer.so
libCpuRenderer.so
```

all these three libraries have the same API (that is, the definitions are in a common header, and all the interfaces are C++ mangling).

Codes for illustration:

Render.h:

```
#ifndef UNTITLED5__RENDERER_H_
#define UNTITLED5__RENDERER_H_
class Renderer {
 public:
  Renderer();
  void OnRender();
};
#endif //UNTITLED5__RENDERER_H_
```

CpuRenderer.cpp:

```
#include "Renderer.h"
#include "iostream"

Renderer::Renderer() {
  std::cout << "CPU renderer created." << std::endl;
}

void Renderer::OnRender() {
  std::cout << "renderer mashes using CPU." << std::endl;
}
```

OpenGLRenderer.cpp:

```
#include "Renderer.h"
#include "iostream"

Renderer::Renderer() {
  std::cout << "OpenGl renderer created." << std::endl;
}

void Renderer::OnRender() {
  std::cout << "renderer mashes using Opengl." << std::endl;
}
```

VulkanRenderer.cpp

```
#include "Renderer.h"
#include "iostream"

Renderer::Renderer() {
  std::cout << "Vulkan renderer created." << std::endl;
}

void Renderer::OnRender() {
  std::cout << "renderer mashes using Vulkan." << std::endl;
}
```

FakeRenderer.cpp:

```
#include "Renderer.h"
#include "iostream"

Renderer::Renderer() {
  std::cout << "Fake renderer created." << std::endl;
}

void Renderer::OnRender() {
  std::cerr << "wrong render backend chose" << std::endl;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "Renderer.h"

int main() {
  Renderer renderer;
  renderer.OnRender();
}
```

and the CMakeLists:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(untitled5)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_library(EngineRenderer SHARED FakeRenderer.cpp)
add_library(OpenGLRenderer SHARED OpenGLRenderer.cpp)
add_library(CpuRenderer SHARED CpuRenderer.cpp)
add_library(VulkanRenderer SHARED VulkanRenderer.cpp)

add_executable(engine main.cpp)
```

Link errors will occur because I didn't link any library to target`engine`, so I have to choose one to link with:
`target_link_libraries(engine PRIVATE EngineRenderer)`

And now the program will print the `Fake renderer created.`. But as you can see, I passed the `EngineRenderer` just to make `engine` built (compiled and linked without unsolved symbols error), but when it comes to the real case, the `libEngineRenderer.so` could be any of OpenGl/CPU/Vulkan, this depends on user's choice.

The concern came since I use `FakeRenderer` implementation to link with the engine, but use a different one with same API when running, I don't know if this is dangerous or not.

In my case, which library to use depends on users' choice. Currently my solution is to link the program using one of the libraries, to make the link stage succeed, than put these libraries into different folders, rename them with the same name (`libEngineRenderer.so`), and set the desired one using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

I tested for a while and it works well, but I'm not sure it is safe to do this, or is there any better way to do this?

P.S.

Why not using `dlopen` and `dlsym`?

The libraries are originally designed as static C++ libraries, but we decide to make user to choose a backend renderer in a launcher, that's why this question comes out. As a matter of engineering, it's not very realistic to change all the C++ APIs to C style (One problem is that all the renderer API is classes, not pure function, let alone C style functions), that's why `dlsym` is hard to use. And other reason is about engineering, the project are almost finished, It's better to make the interfaces calling keeps the same, no matter the library is linked statically or dynamically.

What do you mean by "safety"?

For example will this hack I mentioned above always resolve the right symbols in different libraries, as long as the libraries has an implementation? Will this hack cause crashed somehow? Or is there any other hidden dangerous I don't come up with?

What do you mean by other ways?

For example, any way I can offer a symbol table somehow to the linker, not a real `.so` file. Some sort of "polymorphic" way for loading different libraries which has same API.

P.P.S.
What I mean "safety" is only focus on "compile-link-load&run" aspect, which means to successfully choose a backend to run without problems, loading untrusted libraries is not the "safety" I mean.

Similar question but on Window platform: [Can I change the name of a dll to load at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5474816/can-i-change-the-name-of-a-dll-to-load-at-runtime)

Comment: Please explain in more than a paragraph what "I'm not sure it is safe to do this" means to you.

Comment: Please provide some [mre] in your question.

Comment: Even with the edit I still don't understand your question. In particular what does "I can offer a symbol table" means? **Show some C++ code in your question!**

Comment: Seems like some XY problem

Comment: Are you forbidden to use `dlopen` and `dlsym`. If yes, why? Also **show the exact compilation commands** and the observed output - show the *executed* `g++` commands

Comment: The main reason is the engineering. The engine is almost finished and the API are classes, not pure functions,  that why I prefer to use implicit link rather than explicit link. Btw, I update my question with codes, thanks for helping anyway.

Comment: I don't understand the "implicit link" wording

Comment: It's concepts on Windows: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/linking-an-executable-to-a-dll?view=msvc-160, but I think this concepts still meaningful on Linux. That is, explicit linking is using `dlopen`, implicit linking is linking the `.so` using `-L` when building the program.

Comment: typo here, should be implicit linking.

Comment: No, you need to understand that Windows and Linux are different. As long as you see Linux with your Windows eyes, you'll be in trouble

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with Windows, I just use a concept. I think I make myself clear why I can't use `dlopen`.

Comment: Did you consider publishing the source code of your software as open source on e.g. https://github.com/ ?

Answer (score 0):

You might use [dlopen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) to load at runtime a particular shared library; then use [dlsym(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html) to retrieve symbols from it.  Read also
[*Advanced Linux Programmming*](https://mentorembedded.github.io/advancedlinuxprogramming/) and Drepper's paper [*How to write shared libraries*](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/m/a/1/e/dsohowto.pdf) and Levine's book [*Linkers and loaders*](https://www.amazon.fr/Linkers-Loaders-John-R-Levine/dp/1558604960)

In practice, to ease your coding, all `dlsym`-ed symbols should be declared `extern "C"`. Read the [C++ dlopen minihowto](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/C++-dlopen/index.html) and take inspiration from the source code of libraries like [Qt](https://qt.io/). Otherwise, you need to [demangle C++ identifiers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/ext_demangling.html). This is easily doable, but could be compiler or [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) specific.

See also [ld.so(8)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html) and [ldd(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ldd.1.html), [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html), [readelf(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/readelf.1.html), [execve(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), [elf(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html) and [`c++filt`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/c_002b_002bfilt.html). Ber aware that `ld.so` is internally doing the equivalent of  `dlopen` & `dlsym`

You could also code your [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) to help you. **Your GCC plugin could run whatever checks you want it to do** (e.g. it might fill some [sqlite](https://sqlite.org/) database with mangled C++ names). When your GCC augmented with your GCC plugin compiles the C++ code of some library, it might store whatever data is needed elsewhere (and you just need to update your build automation, e.g. your `Makefile`), and that data would be used later (by your C++ code generator) to generate some other C++ file.

BTW, the Linux [kernel](https://kernel.org/), the [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler, [GNU binutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/) and the [GNU libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) are open source. **Consider studying -and perhaps improving- their source code.**

---

> As a matter of engineering, it's not very realistic to change all the C++ APIs to C style, that's why dlsym is hard for use to use.

You definitely can use `dlsym` on mangled C++ symbols. You just need to figure out (perhaps using [nm(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nm.1.html)) their mangled names.

---

> Is it safe to use one .so file to link but set another library with the same API in LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Certainly not: a rogue shared library could of course do bad things (e.g. calling [unlink(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/unlink.2.html) thru [ntfw(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ntfw.3.html)...) but still provide the same apparent [API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/API).

> For example will this hack I mentioned above always resolve the right symbols in different libraries, as long as the libraries has an implementation? Will this hack cause crashed somehow? Or is there any other hidden dangerous I don't come up with?

Yes, some bad guy might patch your shared library to add bad code inside it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping, but I think this answer is a suggestion more than an solution. The libraries use C++ mangling because they are designed as static libraries before, it's not very realistic to redesign the interface, in turns that `dlsym` is barely imposible to use. At least could you help to just answer if it is safe or not...

Comment: Please improve your question. `*.so` files are supposed to be *shared objects*

Answer (score 0):

> I tested for a while and it works well, but I'm not sure it is safe to do this

Yes.

> or is there any better way to do this?

The better way (the *standard* way) is to avoid using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, and instead use `dlopen()` to open the desired library explicitly.

Instead of linking in `FakeRenderer`, you would link in *facade* renderer, which can look something like this:

```
#include "Renderer.h"
#include "iostream"

static void *handle;
static void (*ctor)(void);
static void (*on_render)(void);

Renderer::Renderer() {
  const char *lib = DecideWhichRendererLibraryShouldBeUsed();
  handle = dlopen(lib, RTLD_LOCAL);
  ctor = dlsym(handle, "_ZN8RendererC1Ev");
  on_render = dlsym(handle, "_ZN8Renderer8OnRenderEv");
}

Renderer::~Renderer() {
  ctor = nullptr;
  on_render = nullptr;
  dlclose(handle);
}

void Renderer::OnRender() {
  (*on_render)();
}
```

The disadvantage is that you will now depend on name mangling. The standard solution is to implement `extern "C"` functions which call the corresponding `C++` ones.