# Loading C# dll in C++/CLI at runtime

Tags: c#, dll, c++-cli

I had a single Visual Studio solution with 2 projects: C# library (dll) and a C++/CLI application project in which this library was used. For simplicity, let's say library code is as follows:

```cs
namespace ClassLibrary
    {
    public interface ISomeClass
        {
            int Add(int a, int b);
        }

    public class SomeClass : ISomeClass
        {
        public int Result = 0;

        public int Add(int a)
            {
                return Result + a;
            }
        }
    }
```

In C++/CLI it was loaded as:

```cpp
#using "relativePathToDll"
gcroot<ClassLibrary::SomeClass^> pSomeClass = gcnew ClassLibrary::SomeClass();

// Function call
pSomeClass->Add(5);
pSomeClass->Add(7);
// ...
```

I need to separate the projects into different Visual Studio solutions. I can gather the path to dll when projects are built/deployed, save it to environmental variables/registry and read it from there at runtime. What would be the best approach to load this dll dynamically at runtime from a given path in C++/CLI project? Are there any better approaches that would not require knowing the path to dll beforehand? Is it worth looking more into ways to modify load-time linking (as decribed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10607348))?

I tried using `LoadLibrary()` but I can not manage to get it working. Most likely I fail to properly export functions on C# side. Also this method would be quite a hassle as it's required to define each function pointer manually (there are way more functions in actual codebase). If I understand correctly, only static functions are allowed for it to work.

I can modify the class library into a COM dll. Examples online show that reference is required before runtime (to .tlb file), which is not possible in this case either.

I have also tried what this [comment by xiay](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46508487) suggested but could not get it working due to lack of examples online.

It might be worth mentioning that my C# library uses some other C# dlls. Will I need to load those separately too?

Comment: Just use standard .NET dynamic loading, such as `Assembly::Load`. In theory you should be able to use External projects in VS if you know up front which DLLs you need.

Comment: Do you have any resources I could look into? I have tried that too, managed to load the assembly but could not find examples how to Invoke functions.

Comment: Loads of examples for C# online https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14479074/c-sharp-reflection-load-assembly-and-invoke-a-method-if-it-exists it shouldn't be hard to translate.

Comment: All you have to do is making sure that the C# dll file ends up in the C++/CLI executable directory.  Use xcopy.exe in the post-build event.

Comment: **C++** ≠ **C++/CLI**.  Two different languages.  This question should not have the `c++` tag.